# Bash script: how to add a section to a config file?

Tags: linux, bash

I know how to find and replace a section in a config file like this:

```
sudo sed -i "s/upload_max_filesize = 2M/upload_max_filesize = 3M/" /etc/php5/cgi/php.ini
```

But how do I add a whole new section to the end of the config file within the bash script?

```
server {
    listen      xx.xx.xx.xx:80;                # your server's public IP address
    server_name  myapp.com;                   # your domain name
    root         /usr/share/nginx/www/myapp/;  # absolute path to your WordPress installation    
}
```

I tried this within the terminal `echo "server { ... }" >> nginx.conf` but I get a

```
-bash: nginx.conf: Permission denied
```

Not sure if this would be ok within the bash script or I would get a permission denied again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the right syntax.

```
echo "....." >> ngix.conf
```

Just make sure you have the correct write permissions for 'ngix.conf'.

> -bash: nginx.conf: Permission denied

This indicates that you have no write privileges.

You can also write the section in an single file like 'new_section.txt' and late add it with:

```
cat new_section.txt >> ngix.conf
```

However I would not advise to add configurations to ngix in this way.
You can use the 'include' statement.

```
include you_conf_path/my_new_config.conf;
```

This way you can group the configuration and have some small config files and not one huge file. Then you can also name your file in a way that helps you find the right one.

Comment: appologies, I do actually a `sudo echo "server { ... }" >> nginx.conf ` nonetheless the redirection doesn't seem to get the sudo permission. I will try that within bash and see if that works better

Comment: Strange as you should be able to write to nearly any file when using sudo.
Maybe you need to stop the server before manipulating the config. Is this your local server or do you work in a shared web space environment?

Comment: funny enough within the bash script it works fine. But not in terminal. :) Good enough for me.

Comment: @Kave - the `sudo` only affects the `echo` command, not the redirection - that's handled by the parent shell. So `echo` runs with `root` privilege (useless, really), and the shell tries to append to the file as the non-root user, which fails. Try `sudo bash -c "echo \"{...}\" >> nginx.conf"` instead - but note that may require some adjustments in your sudo configuration first.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
config="server {\n    listen      xx.xx.xx.xx:80;\n     server_name  myapp.com;               \n    root         /usr/share/nginx/www/myapp/;  =installation    \n }\n"
 in1="text_before_required_input"
 out1=`echo -e $config`;
              in=$in1 out=$out1 perl -pi.nk -e 's/\Q$ENV{"in"}/$ENV{"out"}/g'  file
```

if not above then look into GNU ed  http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/edit-ed